# Embed a conditional XML file in a dll

Tags: msbuild

I want to create a config class for a dll that reads from an embedded resource.  I've created multiple xml files with the configuration for all our different environments. I have a separate configuration for each environment DEV, QA, PROD with matches the prefix on the xml file.

```
.Configuration/DEV.config.xml 
.Configuration/QA.config.xml
.Configuration/PROD.config.xml
```

etc

We've never used MSBuild before and are confused because there seems to be about 3-4 different ways of using it (pre/post build events, xml scripting, custom tasks etc).  All i'm trying to do is rename the respective file to config.xml and embed it in the dll, so that the config class can read it out when it's run.

I've seen similar questions that simply embed a file but none that embed and rename at the same time.  I assume that any sort of embedding would need to be done as a pre-build event.

Normally I would have tried a few bits and bobs but I have no idea where to start with this, if anyone could point me in the right direction I would be extremely grateful.

Update:

so with some help from jlew I should be able to do something like this

```
<ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Configuration\$(Configuration).config.xml" >
        <LogicalName>config.xml</LogicalName>
    </EmbeddedResource>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: What are the task parameters you are using right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably want to do (without having seen your code) is to not rename the input file, but direct MSBuild to use a "logical name" for the resource which is different than the file.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Dev.config.xml">
        <LogicalName>MyRenamedConfig.config.xml</LogicalName>
    </EmbeddedResource>
</ItemGroup>
```

If you are using `csc.exe` directly, you can do something similar with:

```
csc ... /resource:Dev.config.xml,MyRenamedConfig.config.xml
```

Comment: Awesome that sounds like a better idea.  Am I able to just add a conditional onto that EmbeddedResource tag that specifies which configuration it applies to?  like   Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'DEV'.  Then I can just add one of those ItemGroups per Configuration (or have all of them in the same ItemGroup)?

Comment: Yes, that should work.  Alternatively, you could dynamically construct the filename being Included, using a property as part of its name.

Comment: Updated  with some new code, it ended up being so simple, thanks a lot.